# Why does Bash not fail with expanding a missing variable and "-u" flag?

Tags: bash

I was expecting this Bash script to fail, yet it runs successfully:

```bash
set -u
exec {FOO}>/tmp/foo.lock
echo "FOO=$FOO"
```

Also on OnlineGDB: https://onlinegdb.com/3gv34jmGr

I'd expect Bash (5.0.3 as well as 5.1.16) to try expanding `FOO` to a file descriptor and stop because it's undefined and `-u` is set. Not only it runs that line, but it seems to *set* `FOO` to an arbitrary number and finish the script. The standard output is

```
FOO=10
```

What is happening here? Is it a documented Bash feature and where can I find more information about it? Why specifically the number 10?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html):

> Each redirection that may be preceded by a file descriptor number may instead be preceded by a word of the form `{varname}`. In this case, for each redirection operator except `>&-` and `<&-`, the shell will allocate a file descriptor greater than 10 and assign it to `{varname}`.

<sup>(Apparently it should be "greater than or equal to 10".)</sup>

Your `exec {FOO}>/tmp/foo.lock` contains an assignment. `FOO` is no longer undefined.